# zmq pipeline pattern can not work in multiprocess?

Tags: queue, zeromq, pipeline, pyzmq

I think I do not use **`zmq`** in right pattern, what I want to do is:

1. send message by `zmq` in multiprocess
2. accept message in multiple client, but one message should be accept only once

according the second requirements I thought a *`pipeline`* should be ok ( `PUSH/PULL` ), but this mode can not work in multiprocess:

```
def foo(i):
    return i

def producer():
    context = zmq.Context()
    zmq_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    zmq_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559")

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futs = [executor.submit(foo, i) for i in range(10)]
        for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futs):
            work_message = { 'num' : fut.result() }
            zmq_socket.send("test")

producer()
```

so, maybe I should use `PUB/SUB` pattern, but this can not meet the second requirement.

in fact what I want is something like this:

```
PUSH|-----|                  | PULL
PUSH|-----|                  | PULL
PUSH|-----|----- DEVICE -----| PULL
PUSH|-----|                  | PULL
PUSH|-----|                  | PULL
```

Answer (score 0):

### Not exactly, [roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2849157/roger), `ZeroMQ` **`PUSH/PULL`** pattern works

it just does something else than you would like it to do.

`ZeroMQ` is a wonderfull toolbox kit of pre-baked behaviours with immense potential to assemble more complex behaviour models, **where needed**.

Start with understanding the primitive actors, than design your functional requirements.

**`PUSH/PULL`** Formal Communication Scenario gets two players:

---

1st: `PUSH` picks the phone and calls. Whom? The connected `PULL`-side. `PUSH` leaves a voice-mail message to be listened by `PULL`, once it decides to pick it from the voicemail.

---

2nd: `PULL` side ( at some point in time, not necessarily right upon 1.) hears the bell ringing and picks the phone.

---

3rd: `PULL`, if instructed to, processes the received message from  `PUSH`

Nothing more, per se.

---

### Assemblies of `ZeroMQ` primitive components:

yes, there is the way to step farther towards your goal:

Just complement your functional requirements with appropriate `ZeroMQ` primitives inter-connected so as to meet your additional requirements.

**The most trivial-one**, from Chapter 1 of the "**Code Connected, Volume I.**" - a round-robin based forwarding of messages towards a pool-of-"worker"-processes.

[image: Round-robin forwarding to a Pool]

**More specialised assemblies** may create additional functionalities for smart distributed complex behavioral models:

[image]

Typically a "control + signalling" **`SIG_PLANE`** is being implemented in parallel to the primary, functional processing.

Self-diagnostics service, hearbeat/self-healing signalling for non-stop processing scenarios, remote non-blocking logging service, front-end MVC/GUI-plane being the most typical layered design goals.

---

### Your task?

If not interested in more features, just **`.connect()`** your Futures calculating **`PUSH`**-ers towards a `PULL`-ing endpoint.

This middle-step ( a performance / failure analyses singularity ) can collect on it's **`PULL`**-ing entry-side and right go and **`PUSH`** on it's other endpoint, here - on a round-robin basis, towards the pool of actual workers ( who are crowd-waiting for a task with their **`.connect()`**-ed **`PULL`**-er entry endpoints for an incoming task from the "sink"-collector entity ) - a task, from collected FIFO ( beware the buffering capacity and performance overheads you pay for this ), just goes to the ***"next"*** one, down the line.

```
________________________________                                                      _____________________________
process(0)|....[PUSH].connect(A)|-         ________________________________         -|.connect(B)[PULL] process(-1)
process(1)|....[PUSH].connect(A)|--       |                                |       --|.connect(B)[PULL] process(-2)
process(2)|....[PUSH].connect(A)|---   ---.bind(A)[PULL]:NOP:[PUSH].bind(B)|---   ---|.connect(B)[PULL] process(-3)
process(3)|....[PUSH].connect(A)|--       |________________________________|       --|.connect(B)[PULL] process(-4)
...                                                                                                     ...
process(n)|....[PUSH].connect(A)|-                                                  -|.connect(B)[PULL] process(-m)
```

It's that simple.

Enjoy the cool `ZeroMQ` toolkit.

Comment: I would like to know how can I push how can I push in multiple process, so I guess you mean I create a socket for each process?

Comment: yes, I am interested in more features, I want to know more. but now I am worry about the multiprocess problem.